# Упрощения триггера WPF

Tags: wpf, material-design, wpf-toolkit

Добрый утро! Каким образом можно упростить данный триггер и какие замечания будут по данному коду?

```
<Window>...
<Window.Resources>
    <Style
        x:Key="MyButtonAbout"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}">
       <Setter Property="Content">
           <Setter.Value>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <materialDesign:PackIcon
                       Width="25"
                       Height="25"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       Kind="CommentAlertOutline" />
                   <TextBlock
                       Margin="3"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       Text="About" />
               </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
       </Setter> 
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                Width="25"
                                Height="25"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Foreground="Yellow"
                                Kind="CommentAlertOutline" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="3"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Foreground="Orange"
                                Text="About" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
     <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonAbout}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно переустанавливать `Content` в триггере, если вы хотите изменить свойства уже существующего элемента.

Меняйте свойства через `<Setter TargetName="MyElementName" Property="PropertyName" Value="MyValue" />`, предварительно установив имя для элемента.

При этом `Content` нужно вынести в `ControlTemplate`, чтобы была возможность обращаться в сеттере к элементу через `TargetName`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <materialDesign:PackIcon
                   Name="Icon"
                   Width="25"
                   Height="25"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   Kind="CommentAlertOutline" />
               <TextBlock
                   Name="Text"
                   Margin="3"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   Text="About" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
            <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Затем в стиле устанавливаем свойство `Template`:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonAbout" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Если в стиле вы больше ничего не делаете, то можно применить шаблон напрямую к кнопке, без создания стиля:

```
<Button Content="ClickMe" Template="{StaticResource CustomButtonTemplate}" />
```

Более подробно можете [прочесть здесь.](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/Template/level17/17_6.php)

Comment: Один в один делал, несколько часов назад.. не распознает targetname

Comment: @UserLevel0, Да, действительно так не будет работать. Вам нужно вынести все из свойства `Content` в `ControlTemplate` и уже у него устанавливать триггеры. Сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: @UserLevel0, Исправил ответ.